# how to recursively search a matrix to find a path

Tags: c++, recursion

i am trying to recursively travel to all the coordinates in grid[][], but i'm having trouble implementing the logic properly, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.
my program keeps crashing when i run it in my opengl code. i'm trying to visualize breadth first search path finding in opengl.

you can find the entire source file here: https://pastebin.com/Jae9f75M

```
int findPath(Grid* current,int x, int y)
{
    if (!pathFound)
    {
        if (current->isObstacle() || current->isTraversed())
        {
            //do nothing
            std::cout << "obstacle, traversed or start found \n";
        }
        else if (current->isEndPoint())
        {
            pathFound = true;
            std::cout << "end found \n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "probable path found \n";
            if (x >= 0 && x < GRID_SIZE*2 && y >= 0 && y < GRID_SIZE*2)
            {
                current->setTraversed();

                findPath(grid[x + 1][y], x + 1, y); //right
                findPath(grid[x - 1][y], x - 1, y); //left
                findPath(grid[x][y + 1], x, y + 1); //top
                findPath(grid[x][y - 1], x, y - 1); //bottom
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Even then, a recursive depth-first search on even a modest grid will quickly stack overflow.

Comment: Recursion is not safe for anything that is not guaranteed to be atmost logarithmic in size. Use Dijsktra.

Comment: I think the main issue is not the recursion, but the fact that this is a completely blind depth-first-search. If you replace the recursion with a loop, you'll have an awfully long loop and that's still not good. Perhaps an algorithm like `A*` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Stef i'm doing this as part of a college project and my first idea was to use A*, but since BFS was easier and i have a deadline to meet, i thought BFS would be easier to implement

Answer (score 0):

One main issue is your data structure the way I see it (once you can clean your code, the other issues should also be jumping in your face). Instead of raw `Grid*` and `[][]` (never use this unless you really have to !)and whatever you could suit your datastructure to whatever algorithm you need to do:

*simplified pseudocode:*

```
struct GridEntry {
  size_t x;
  size_t y;
  bool operator<(...) {return false;//implement how grid entry should compare}
};

//...

{
   std::vector<GridEntry> my_grid_;

   //.. fill grid whatever
   {
     std::sort(my_grid_.begin(), ...)
     //.. search grid, find path, whatever.
   }
}
```

If you want lookups use a `map` instead, ala: `std::map<GridEntry> my_grid;`